# How do I join tables in MS Access using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Hi guys I'm new to MS Access and am really struggling with using VBA to join tables. Essentially I need a button that will join tables upon clicking. While this topic has been done to death I can't seem to understand how this works.

**Question**: Assume I have three tables: Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3. I want to join Tab1 and Tab2 by a common variable: ID and Tab2 and Tab3 by a common variable ID2. How can I write this in VBA to return a data table which combines Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3.

i.e.

```
Tab1        
ID  Name    Age
1   John    22
2   Conor   21
3   Sarah   23



Tab2        
ID  Name    Location
1   John    California
2   Conor   New York
3   Sarah   Washington

Tab3                
ID2 Grade           
1   A           
2   E           
3   C
```

Should result in:

```
Result              
ID  Name    Age Location    Grade
1   John    22  California  A
2   Conor   21  New York    E
3   Sarah   23  Washington  C
```

Comment: I suggest you start with the query designer, then switch to SQL view, and make your way from there.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the additional question. @Andre this is the part I'm struggling with. I'm not quite sure how I should write the code.

Comment: access doesn't use SQL but something that calls SQL for itself. Use (unnecessary in real databases) parentheses around your join expressions.

Comment: @CetinBasoz ... not clear what your comment means. MS Access maintains an SQL dialect (of the Jet/ACE SQL engine which are .dll files) like other RDBMs. And no two dialects are the same!

Comment: Really? :) Check ANSI SQL.

Comment: @br93...simply build your queries in advance and call it as needed. And this is preferred since Access engine caches best execution plan when saving queries.

Comment: @CetinBasoz  This conversation could get out of hand if we go back to standards.  Perhaps excepting a few edge cases, you're not going to find a "perfect" database that implements any ANSI standard without exceptions.  That's not the point of this question... it is about learning how to write basic SQL statements... and Access SQL is similar enough to others that there is no need to confuse.

Comment: Writing a JOIN is basic in any SQL database and access makes it hard and out of standards, right at doing such a basic necessity. It doesn't need to be perfect but at least do not do such basic things in the weirdest way.

Comment: See [Performing Joins Using Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/perform-joins-using-access-sql?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Also, doing this in VBA will require executing the SQL using DAO and working with Recordset and related objects.  This is an entire topic that cannot be taught here.  As @Parfait mentioned, you'll need to study more details away from SO.  Good luck.

Comment: @CPerkins, sorry for providing an "answer" to the OP. His question was way too simple to be answered instead of providing links.

Comment: @CetinBasoz  I have no problem with anyone providing an answer.  Had I more time, perhaps I would have posted my own with VBA code showing the SQL statement and DAO calls to access and use the recordset.  Now, whether an answer is high quality can be judged by whether it answers the particulars of the question and if is technically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (Tab1
inner JOIN Tab2 ON tab1.Id = Tab2.ID)
inner JOIN Tab3 ON tab2.id2 = tab3.id2
```

Ugly I know.

This SQL is based on your edited question with sample data:

```
SELECT tab1.*, tab2.Location, tab3.Grade
FROM (Tab1
inner JOIN Tab2 ON tab1.Id = Tab2.ID)
inner JOIN Tab3 ON tab2.id2 = tab3.id2
```

Comment: @Parfait, Right, another access peculiarity.

Comment: @Cetlin Basoz this is exactly the type of code I'm looking for as I have no  prior experience with MS Access SQL. It would be appreciated if we can find a solution using something like this.

Comment: @br93 ... StackOverflow is not a tutorial site. There are books, blogs, videos, tutorials, talks on MS Access and SQL in general. Make an attempt, come back with a specific issue.

Comment: @br93, I gave you the solution above.

Comment: @CetinBasoz apologies, I thought Parfait said it would fail in Access SQL.

Comment: No, it was just another peculiarity of access that I corrected. Some are down voting just because I touched their nerves saying the facts about access. BTW you initially said ID and ID2 but now I see some sample data from you with no ID2.

Comment: @CPerkins what are you talking about. I posted an answer. Isn't the one you down voted an answer? I don't know what "contempt" means. SQL dialect is not standard, if you meant it and I stand for that. Why can't you be just object about its weaknesses. And also I don't see your answer.

Comment: @CetinBasoz thank you so much! Your solution worked, I've embedded it within my VBA code and can now use a button to run this from my form. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Probably, the easiest way to do this, is to do it in SQL, and then convert the SQL to VBA.

Creating the form

The form just needs two text boxes, and a command button. SQL statements can be quite long, so you put the text boxes on different pages of a tab control.

```
Create a new form (in design view.)
Add a tab control.
In the first page of the tab control, add a unbound text box.
Set its Name property to txtSql.
Increase its Height and Width so you can see many long lines at once.
In the second page of the tab control, add another unbound text box.
Name it txtVBA, and increase its height and width.
Above the tab control, add a command button.
Name it cmdSql2Vba.
Set its On Click property to [Event Procedure].
Click the Build button (...) beside this property.
When Access opens the code window, set up the code like this:

Private Sub cmdSql2Vba_Click()
    Dim strSql As String
    'Purpose:   Convert a SQL statement into a string to paste into VBA code.
    Const strcLineEnd = " "" & vbCrLf & _" & vbCrLf & """"

    If IsNull(Me.txtSQL) Then
        Beep
    Else
        strSql = Me.txtSQL
        strSql = Replace(strSql, """", """""")  'Double up any quotes.
        strSql = Replace(strSql, vbCrLf, strcLineEnd)
        strSql = "strSql = """ & strSql & """"
        Me.txtVBA = strSql
        Me.txtVBA.SetFocus
        RunCommand acCmdCopy
    End If
End Sub
```

Using the form

To use the form:

```
Open your query in SQL View, and copy the SQL statement to clipboard (Ctrl+C.)
Paste into the first text box (Ctrl+V.)
Click the button.
Paste into a new line in your VBA procedure (Ctrl+V.)
```

[image]

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-71.html